# How can I make a while loop menu without the function thinking its false?

Tags: python, function, while-loop, menu

```
import os
import time

#create a function that asks for user login credentials in order to verify that they're elligible to write to the .dat file

def rpk(intu, password):
    global srk, trk 
    f16 = open("credentials.dat", "r")
    rsk = "incorrect username"
    msk = "incorrect password or username"
    j = f16.read()
    nfk = j.split("\n")
    srk = nfk[0]
    trk = nfk[1]
    if intu == srk:
      if password == trk:
        return "Success!, you have access to the data."
      else:
        return msk
    else:
      return rsk
    f16.close()
def kws(sen, arc):
  f22 = open("credentials.dat", "w", encoding= "utf-8")
  rex = f22.write(sen, "\n")
  rem = f22.write(arc, "\n")
  return "complete!"


userin = ''
passwordin = ''
```

Here, I need to define them but the problem is that everytime i run this, it always shows the print statement that occurs whenever the input is false. How do i get around this and make sure
the while loop acts as a menu???

```
while False:
  userin = input("Enter the username: ")
  passwordin = input("Enter the password: ")
  x = rpk(userin, passwordin)    
  print(x)
```

Comment: `while False:` will never execute anything.

Comment: What do you think the False signifies in `while False:`?

Comment: "I need to define them" What is "them"?

Comment: You should use `while True:` and provide a way of exiting the program

Answer (score 1):

You can use if statement to break the loop. for example:

```
while True:
  userin = input("\nEnter the username: ")
  passwordin = input("\nEnter the password: ")
  x = rpk(userin, passwordin)    
  print(x)
  quit = input("To quit please enter 'q': ")
  if quit == 'q':
    break
```